# Can't connect to a remote SQL server 2008 instance

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to deploy my Database to a web server but I can't get a connection to the SQL server installed in the web server using management studio 2008. I have already enabled TCP/IP protocol in sql server configuration manager. I also disabled the windows firewall but no result. I always get this error message :

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to sql2008.metropol-beauty.com,1430.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error  occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP
>   Provider,  error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer
>   available.) (Microsoft  SQL Server, Error: 64)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a hardware firewall in between, if so, is it protocol aware (Watchguard Firewalls are the ones I have run into).  If so, sometimes they like to detect a protocol and muck it up (esp. if it is an older version of the firmware, and the software you are using is newer).

Comment: No there isn't such a thing. I could connect once with the same options but just once I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Can you try with an invalid login? Does it say "Login Failed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the SQL port which is 1433 is open between the web server and e database server.  You also need to ensure that the SQL sever is listening for remote connections.  This can be cycled in the SQL Server Configurion Tool.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server running as a named instance?  I have seen something like this before and ended up installing the native client tools on the server and configuring my SQL server up in that.  Seemed to resolve my issue, give it ago and see what happens.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=8824